# can't unserialize - PHP 7.1.22

Tags: php, string, serialization

I serialize the associate array using PHP core serialize

```
$additional_email = serialize($customer->getData('addtionalemail'));
```

After that save this value in Mysql database

```
s:209:"a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:16:"additional_email";s:13:"test@test.com";s:9:"record_id";s:1:"0";s:26:"apply_to-prepared-for-send";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"0";}s:8:"apply_to";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"0";}s:10:"initialize";s:4:"true";}}}";
```

When I unserialized the above value, it didn't work. I used the solutions like base_64_encode and decode before serialize and unserialize but it does not solve the issue, also used preg_match solutions but no luck.

I use [unserialize online tool](https://www.unserialize.com/s/11fca97d-551c-2fc8-e3ad-000072119a7c), that will also not able to unserialize the above string. Something wrong with the serialized value, can anyone point me the right direction?

Comment: What do you have in `$customer->getData('addtionalemail')`? Can you show us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have somehow `serialize`d the value twice. Running `unserialize` twice undoes that:

```
print_r(unserialize(unserialize('s:209:"a:1:{i:0;a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:16:"additional_email";s:13:"test@test.com";s:9:"record_id";s:1:"0";s:26:"apply_to-prepared-for-send";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"0";}s:8:"apply_to";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"0";}s:10:"initialize";s:4:"true";}}}";')));
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
      [additional_email] => test@test.com
      [record_id] => 0
      [apply_to-prepared-for-send] => Array (
         [0] => 0 
      )
      [apply_to] => Array (
        [0] => 0
      )
      [initialize] => true
    )
  )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/vNrT7)